# block threads on certain conditions in java

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Maybe this is a really dumb question, but please hear me out. I have a use case where I get many concurrent requests to do something for a particular input date. If there are two concurrent requests received for the same input date, the subsequent request should not proceed till the prior request has finished completely (for good reasons). What is the best way to use standard java.util.concurrent components to achieve this? My initial thoughts were around having a LockFactory which will vend locks and keep a copy to indicate that it is in use and on which the subsequent request will await(). However, this seems to have lot of boiler-plate code - any simpler trick that is eluding me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you queue up all the requests and process them one at a time?  If performance is reasonable, queues solve a lot of concurrency problems.

Comment: Do you need queued tasks for the same input date to occur "in the order they arrive" (being *fair*), or does it not matter which one runs next, so long as no two of them run at the same time?

Comment: @user949300 queuing up all requests is not a viable alternative here. The requests are originating in real time.

Comment: @seh Roughly the same order (though not really strictly)

Comment: Note that using locks implies using a queue (or, if you like, a set of waiters). How else would the scheduler know which threads are blocked on which locks, waiting to be woken up? Of course, it's one queue per lock, which may be acceptable to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hash individual locks on the date's time.

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<Long,Lock> dateLock = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long,Lock>();

public static Lock getLock(Date date){
  Lock lock = dateLock.get(date.getTime());  
  if(lock == null){
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();  
    Lock temp =dateLock.putIfAbsent(lock); 
    lock = temp == null ? lock : temp;
  }
 return lock;
}
```

If you need the same day and not necessarily the exact date in milliseconds you can do something like

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<String,Lock> dateLock = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Lock>();

public static Lock getLock(Date date){ 
  String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM\dd\yyyy").parse(date);
  Lock lock = dateLock.get(formattedDate);  
  if(lock == null){
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();  
    Lock temp =dateLock.putIfAbsent(lock); 
    lock = temp == null ? lock : temp;
  }
 return lock;
}
```

Then any request that needs mutual exclusion on a date

```
Date date = ...;

Lock lock = getLock(date);
lock.lock();
```

and so forth

Comment: using ConcurrentMap<Date, Lock> should also do the trick, right? I am choosing this answer as it also clearly mentions how to achieve the blocking between contending threads without need for additional queues though DJClayworth was also close. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Kilokahn It probably will though I try to avoid using/assuming much from the Date class other then the `getTime()`

Comment: Note that with this approach, there is no safe way to purge any of the previously-bound lock instances. It's a "grow-only" solution. Purging locks would require locking at a higher level -- perhaps on the map itself -- which, depending on how often you would attempt such purging, challenges the throughput of threads looking to process requests.

Comment: @Kilokahn While you won't process the same date concurrently this solution will kill your ability to process in parallel when receiving multiple jobs with the same date.  You really defeat the purpose of having multiple threads.  If you get a few jobs with the same date you will have all your threads waiting on the lock, effectively reverting to single threading until all the jobs with that date have been processed.  Instead those threads should continue working on the jobs with other dates.  Depending on the ranges of dates you will also have the memory leak that seh points out.

Comment: @Heathen the memory argument is a fair one (which seh already made), but I can't see how you can make a concurrency argument as it is part of his requirement.  "If there are two concurrent requests received for the same input date, the subsequent request should not proceed till the prior request has finished completely"  This achieves exactly that, and the OP needs to be aware of the serial trade-off.  I am not sure if you read the OP's question.

Comment: @John Vint You don't want a thread to be blocking while there are jobs outstanding.  Consider 2 threads with jobs [D1-1, D1-2, D2].  
T1 processes D1-1, T2 - Blocks on D1-2, T1 finishes and T2 processes D1-2, T1 processes D2.  You can see that concurrency is affected by T2 blocking.  Instead T2 should move directly on to D2, then either T1 or T2 can pick up D1-2.

Comment: @John Vint Now consider what would happen if you received 50 or 60 of the same dates? Effective single threaded processing.  Surely the requirement was to process the same date sequentially while still allowing all other jobs to be processed.

Comment: Where are you getting that D2 should be processed if D1 is currently in use?  What if the OP needs dates to be processed in ascending order?  I think you are making too many assumptions the OP didn't mention.

Comment: "Surely the requirement was to process the same date sequentially while still allowing all other jobs to be processed"  Again he says that no where, he only says (and I am quoting it again) "If there are two concurrent requests received for the same input date, the subsequent request should not proceed till the prior request has finished completely "

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you have to queue up your requests and process them one at a time.  So perhaps a BlockingQueue from java.util.concurrent?

Comment: Only if the requests are from the same date then should it be queued. Otherwise the requests should be processed in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a ThreadPoolExecutor to perform requests in several threads. Also you need to have a list of input dates, that are processed now. This list should have synchronous accessors and putIfAbsent method. Before sending a task to queue check that it's input date is not processed now. If it is processed now, move this task to the end of the queue and try to run next task. When task is completed, remove its input date from the list.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have a system in which threads can take input requests and process them, without missing or duplicating any, taking care of any locking issues. All you then need is for each thread to record somewhere the input date of the thing it is currently working on. When a thread examines an input request it first checks the date, looks to see if any requests with that date are currently being processed, and if they are then it leaves that request in the queue and takes the next one.

You will need a certain amount of locking to ensure that the 'currently working on entry' isn't in the process of being updated when you test it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple trick you're looking for is the thread pool "with in order processing" pattern.  [Here is a thread which explain the pattern and various solutions to implement it](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t676760-pattern-for-queue-thread-pool-with-in-order-processing.html)